# Java OutOfMemoryError even with Correct Structuring?

Tags: java, eclipse, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am working with 2D `int` arrays in Java, that are square and can have ~30000 elements in a row and column, which means there are 30000^2*4 bytes in the array, which is less than 5GB (and I have much more than 5GB of memory available).

My basic structure of the program is this:

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Graph g = ...; // read from file
        System.out.println(B.computeSomethingBig(g));
    }
}

public class B {
     public static computeSomethingBig(Graph g) {
         int numVertices = g.numVertices();
         System.out.println(numVertices); // ~30000 maximum
         int[][] array = new int[numVertices][numVertices];
         // ... other computations
     }
}
```

Now, in Eclipse, I am running `main` in class `A` with these arguments:

```
-Xms5g -Xmx10g
```

I have `numVertices` print out a value around 30000, and setting the minimum heap size (`-Xms`) seems more than necessary. However, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Comment: Do you think you can declare such an array?

Comment: 30'000 by 30'000????

Comment: @usar What do you mean by that?

Comment: You are declaring an array with 30 000 integers with 30 000 integers inside each of them

Comment: Suppose an integer is 4 bytes, make the calculation

Comment: @usar Right, but this is well within the memory bounds on my machine. Why wouldn't that work?Doing the math yields around 3.3GB of data.

Comment: Not your machine, your JVM

Comment: Oh sorry I thought integers were 4 bytes, but are 8. The # of bytes = 30000^2*8, since integers are 8 bytes. Converting to GB gives 6.7GB.

Comment: Actually, based on your assumptions, it yields around 6.71gb, it's equivalent to doing something like `int[] a1 = new int[30000]; int[] a2 = new int[30000];`

Comment: @Ryan Good job dude ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, correct!

Comment: Try to get a stacktrace. The array allocation itself should be fine, especially as only the first dimension gets initialized automatically.

Comment: @Thilo `new T[int_value][int_value]` initializes both dimensions (`new T[int_value][/*empty*/]` would do only first) and @Ryan `int` is indeed 4 bytes. Creating (only) `int[30000][30000]` works for me, in 7u55 on x64 with `-Xmx4G`, and `Runtime .totalMemory() - .freeMemory()` confirms it uses slightly over 3.6e9 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

Running the following:

```
public class A {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                int numVertices = 30000;
                int[][] array = new int[numVertices][numVertices];
        }
}
```

without any parameters, ie `java A` leads to OOM error. Running `java -Xms5g -Xmx10g A` works. I suspect numVertices is bigger than what you expected. Why don't you output it before allocating to make sure.

Also consider that your `Graph`, or other objects in the application could be using heap space too.

Comment: So basically, the heap is only specific to the main method it was called from? and not any method that it calls (maybe in some other class)?

Comment: @Ryan No, the Java heap is the space reserved for objects in your application. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/garbage_collect.html

Comment: So then why would the solution you have work and not mine? I am creating a 2D array in the same manner, just in a different method.

Comment: Also consider a one-dimensional array instead. There is some overhead involved in a two-dimensional array (as opposed to manually mapping coordinated into a one-dimensional array). At these sizes, this may matter.

Comment: @jdphenix Interesting - running that gives both InitialHeapSize and MaxHeapSize to be 2^32 (4294967296).

Comment: @jdphenix Mac OS X 10.9.4. It is running Java 6.

Comment: I also ran on Mac OS X 10.9.4

Comment: @triggerNZ Would Java 6 be the problem? Because I doubt it. Or maybe since the {Initial,Max}HeapSize is 2^32, is there a switch that makes Java run 64-bit?

Comment: @Ryan java -version gives: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode). What does yours say?

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to face is the case where no individual area inside heap (such as eden, survivor or old) is big enough to accommodate the data structure you are trying to allocate. For example - your 5G heap can by default be divided as following (note that this is platform specific):

- Eden 1.5G
- Two Survivor spaces 0.25G each
- Old 3G

More fine-grained configuration by tweaking the ratios of the different areas will sort the things out for you.